# React Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop with High Ordered Compenents

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I have a react App.I have this error.
I know every maaped element must have a unique key prop. I also tried `key={Math.random()}` to debug the error but unfortunately I could not able to see the error.
The app works but I want to get rid of this error.
Any ideas will be heplful to me.

[image: error about mapping]

I have a Skills component and it is wrapped with 2 HOC components for global styling issues.

Skills.tsx is like this

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { Tooltip } from 'react-tooltip'
import { AppWrap, MotionWrap } from '../../wrapper';
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';
import './Skills.scss';
import 'react-tooltip/dist/react-tooltip.css';


function Skills() {

  const [experiences, setExperiences] = useState([] as any);
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState<any[]>([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "experiences"]';
    const skillsQuery = '*[_type == "skills"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setExperiences(data);
    });

    client.fetch(skillsQuery).then((data) => {
      setSkills(data);
    });

  }, []);

  
  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="head-text">Skills & Experiences</h2>
      <div className="app__skills-container">
        <motion.div className='app__skills-list'>
          {skills.map((skill) => (
            <motion.div
              className='app__skills-item app__flex'
              whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
              transition={{ duration: .5 }}
              key={skill._createdAt}
            >
              <div className='app__flex' style={{ backgroundColor: skill.bgColor }}>
                <img src={urlFor(skill.icon).url()} alt={skill.name} />
              </div>
              <p className='p-text'>{skill.name}</p>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </motion.div>
        <div className='app__skills-exp'>
          {experiences.map((experience: any) => (
            <motion.div
              className='app__skills-exp-item'
              key={experience._id}>
              <div className="app__skills-exp-year">
                <p className="bold-text">{experience.year}</p>
              </div>
              <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-works">
                {experience.works.map((work:any) => (
                  <>
                    <motion.div
                      whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
                      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                      className="app__skills-exp-work"
                      data-tip
                      key={work._key} // _key
                      id={work._key}
                      data-tooltip-delay-hide={500}
                      data-tooltip-variant="info"
                    >
                      <h4 className="bold-text">{work.name}</h4>
                      <p className="p-text">{work.company}</p>
                    </motion.div>
                    <Tooltip
                      anchorId={work._key}
                      className="skills-tooltip"
                      content={work.desc}
                      float={true}
                      id="tooltip-anchor-10"
                    />
                  </>
                ))}
              </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}


export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(Skills, 'app__skills'),
  'skills',
  'app__whitebg',
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And I have a MotionWrap component inner HOC component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const MotionWrap = (Component :React.FunctionComponent, classNames:string[] | string ='') => function HOC() {
  return (
    <motion.div
      whileInView={{ y: [100, 50, 0], opacity: [0, 0, 1] }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
      className={`${classNames} app__flex`}
    >
      <Component />
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default MotionWrap;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And The most outer HOC component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationDots, ConnectMedia } from '../components'

function AppWrap( Component:React.FunctionComponent, idName : string, classNames:string | string[] ='') {
  return function HOC22() {
    return (
        <div id={idName} className={`app__container ${classNames}`}>
          <ConnectMedia />
          <div  className="app__wrapper app__flex">
            <Component />
    
            <div className="copyright">
              <p className="p-text">@2023 BARIŞ</p>
              <p className="p-text">All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <NavigationDots active={idName} />
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default AppWrap
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you're seeing the error or not? I'm confused.

Comment: I can see the error but I can't find its source

Comment: `{experience.works.map((work:any) => (` returns `<>...</>`. Where is the key here? Replace those with <React.Fragment> and add a key to it (<> cant have keys)

Comment: By the help of  @SergeySosunov error is gone like this  ` <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-works">
                {experience.works.map((work:any) => (
                  <React.Fragment key={work._key}> ........`